# How do I run Apache 2 on Alpine in Docker?

Tags: docker, apache2, alpine-linux

According to [Alpine wiki](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Apache) I have to run `rc-service apache2 start`after installation of Apache 2. However, there's no `rc-service` in the Alpine running inside the container. How do I get the service command to run inside Docker container?

Comment: It's not a duplicate question, but still relevant. Thanks for noting that.

Answer (score 12):

[`gliderlabs/docker-alpine` issue 183](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/183) illustrate the docker Alpine image has no `service` or `rc-service`.

You can see instead [`nimmis/docker-alpine-apache`](https://github.com/nimmis/docker-alpine-apache) based on [`nimmis/docker-alpine-micro`](https://github.com/nimmis/docker-alpine-micro), which includes a runit, used to handle starting and shutting down processes automatically started.

That initd will start the [apache2 script](https://github.com/nimmis/docker-alpine-apache/blob/master/apache2), which calls:

```
exec /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f /web/config/httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 10):

Alpine does not have rc-service installed by default. You need to install it (either as part of your Dockerfile build process or manually in the container).

The secret invocation is:

```
apk add openrc --no-cache
```

If you want to run it from outside the container (say docker run), then use:

```
docker run [options etc] bin/ash -c "apk add openrc --no-cache"
```

PS: rc-service is good for other things and stuff like mariadb (also not included in alpine)

Comment: Quite impresive. I don't know the rc doesn't installed by default. Thanks for mentioning.