# How to deploy a Laravel Web Application on Alpine Linux using Docker?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, docker, alpine-linux

I am successfully deploying a Laravel Web Application on ECS using a base image from PHP, in particular `7.3-apache-stretch` from https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

Being well aware of the discussion about [Alpine Linux](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) Images in Docker (granting significative reductions in the final image dimension), I wanted to give it a run, to see how it performed. Unfortunately, while with the CLI version it was very easy (using `7.3-cli-alpine3.9`), there is no apache-enabled version. What I would need is a `Dockerfile` to use as a base for my developments.

**Apache Only**

Browsing SO, I found [How do I run Apache 2 on Alpine in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035726/how-do-i-run-apache-2-on-alpine-in-docker/43632383) that brought my attention to https://github.com/nimmis/docker-alpine-apache, that enables apache, but PHP is completely missing, so I'd have to integrate this.

**Running Apache/NGINX and PHP with FCGI**

This other question [Alpine variants of PHP and Apache/httpd in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303775/alpine-variants-of-php-and-apache-httpd-in-docker) brings us closer, but implies theuse of two containers, that is not what I want to have.

How should the `Dockerfile` be to let me deploy a Laravel Web Application off the shelf ?

Comment: 1 thing I would like to say: Laravel needs a webserver with php and a database at the very least right. Both are seperate services, so also seperate containers. So here is a docker-compose I made that you can copy off off https://gist.github.com/thomasmoors/f86d69031de1562d55287f4a69b33137

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, this is actually useful, even if being based on `php:7.2-apache`, we would still be using debian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After two days of attempts, I finally arrived to a point in which I am able to deploy my Laravel Application on a php-enabled apache container. Since the number of issues found was countless, here is the final `Dockerfile`, and an explanation of the sections:

```
# PHP Images can be found at https://hub.docker.com/_/php/
FROM php:7.3-alpine3.9

# The application will be copied in /home/application and the original document root will be replaced in the apache configuration 
COPY . /home/application/ 

# Custom Document Root
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/application/public

# Concatenated RUN commands
RUN apk add --update apache2 php7-apache2 php7-mbstring php7-session php7-json php7-pdo php7-openssl php7-tokenizer php7-pdo php7-pdo_mysql php7-xml php7-simplexml\
    && chmod -R 777 /home/application/storage \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /home/application \
    && mkdir -p /run/apache2 \
    && sed -i '/LoadModule rewrite_module/s/^#//g' /etc/apache2/httpd.conf \
    && sed -i '/LoadModule session_module/s/^#//g' /etc/apache2/httpd.conf \
    && sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/localhost/htdocs!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/httpd.conf \
    && sed -i 's/AllowOverride\ None/AllowOverride\ All/g' /etc/apache2/httpd.conf \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && rm  -rf /tmp/* /var/cache/apk/*

# Launch the httpd in foreground
CMD rm -rf /run/apache2/* || true && /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

This is a short list of the operations that I made in the `Dockerfile`

1. First of all, I base everything on a PHP image, based on alpine distribution.
2. I copy all of my Laravel source code on `/home/application`
3. I set the  document root to my `public` Laravel folder
4. Request the installation of the operative system packages via `apk` (all of them were required for my Laravel application). A full list of the available packages can be found on http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/x86_64/
5. Extend permissions on the `storage` folder
6. Change the owner of the whole `/home/application/` folder
7. Enable all the needed modules (different modules could be required, depending of the application)
8. Change the document root in the `httpd.conf` file
9. Enable the `AllowOverride All` instruction
10. Enable the `pdo_mysql` extension (otherwise commands will not be able to access mysql)
11. Clean the cache of the packaging system
12. Run `httpd`

Using this `Dockerfile`, it's now possible to run all of the Laravel Web Applications, it will just be a matter of copying the application source code in `/home/application/`

Comment: You must be Italian because you are very operative, significative and consistative.